# Redirect URL, but then homepage link to still work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I wish for a WP site to redirect to a certain page, but then when they click on "Home" in the menu for it to go the standard homepage.

Should this be done via .htaccess or PHP or..?

Thanks!

Comment: I really didn't understand your question ?

Comment: I would like when someone visits http://boythefilm.com for the page to redirect to http://boythefilm.com/american-theatres. But then I would like them to still be able to click the "Home" link to view the homepage animation not the theatre list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then why don't you make the "boythefilm.com/american-theatres" your static landing page from settings->reading in wordpress admin ?

Comment: Because it is a post. But I will check with the client that they are happy for me to transfer the content to a page. Thanks!

Comment: What is your home page, static page or blog ?

Comment: The homepage is a static page

Comment: Hi Sheikh Heera. While your suggestion to change the WP homepage isn't exactly what I was wanting to do (to avoid all home links going to new page), it is the solution I went with. If you want to make it an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Answered as you said and so many thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the "boythefilm.com/american-theatres" your static landing page from settings->reading in wordpress admin/backend. hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: While your suggestion isn't exactly what I was wanting to do (I wanted to avoid all home links going to new page), it is still the solution I went with for simplicity's sake! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your header.php

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/' && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/american-theatres') header('Location: http://boythefilm.com/american-theatres');
```

Comment: Thanks seferov, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I pasted the following into my header.php file `<?php if(!is_home()) header('Location: http://boythefilm.com/american-theatres'); // Temporary redirect ?>` - looks right doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it does. But if you want to redirect all to a page that is inside the wordpress site, we should add exception to the code. otherwise it would create infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, the page is inside the WP site. Basically I want to redirect boythefilm.com to boythefilm.com/american-theatres, but still want the "Home" link to work in the nav. Hmmm. Cookies?

Comment: Thanks again! I pasted your new code in the header.php file within the <head> tag, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything: http://boythefilm.com

Comment: To be sure, add it before `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` in `index.php` located in the document root

Comment: Ooh, that gives an error in the browser. Doesn't like the server redirect. Have removed it.